# How to post data to a Keycloak required action using Postman/JMeter

Tags: jmeter, postman, single-sign-on, keycloak, load-testing

I have a custom OTP required action, it is presented to every new user after they finished the registration. Now I need to perform a load test on this required action using Postman/JMeter. One thing I noticed from the browser is that when I submit an OTP through browser, Keycloak actually performs a POST request to endpoint `https://{BASE_URL}/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}/login-actions/required-action?session_code={SESSION_CODE}&execution=required-action-custom-otp&client_id=myApp&tab_id={TAB_ID}` and Keycloak sends the OTP data as the body request.

But so far I could not find a way to use those information to POST the OTP data using Postman/JMeter and unable to find the documentation for this case. What can I do to perform the load test using Postman/JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some documentation of your APIs and Keycloak then you'll have to make reference to it.

If not then you'll have to inspect the authentication request manually:
F12 in your browser then you select the tab 'network', then you simulate the login action manually; so input your user data and login.

You'll be able to see the network traffic, you have to find the login POST request and identify the HTTP¨headers that are sent. One of them should be the authentication type (a popular one is OAauth2 for example). Then you'll need to identify how the user credentials (username and password) is encoded and you implement the same thing in PostMAN. In the past I saw the following example to send user credentials:

**username_encoded_in_64base:password_encoded_in_64base**

If you succeed to send the request in PostMAN then you'll have to send just the same request (header,content) in your Jmeter.

This approach have worked for me in the past for so long.